# Sqoop accessing specific Oracle Schema

Tags: oracle, hadoop, schema, sqoop

I have an Oracle database that has a number of schemas in it, a master schema and a bunch of children schemas. My master schema has privileges so that it can create/destroy/access tables in any of the children.

My question is, I'm doing a list-tables in Sqoop on the master schema and I I'm seeing all the children tables get included in the results.

Is there a way to distinguish which schema those tables belong to? I have some names that overlap and it's impossible to tell which table goes where at the moment.

mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this issue is being solved by SQOOP-741 [1].

Links:

1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-741

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are selecting from ALL_TABLES.  If you are logged in as the "master" schema user, you want to select from USER_TABLES.  If you are selecting from ALL_TABLES you need to filter by OWNER=.

Comment: how is it that you can govern what table it gets selected from in Sqoop? I don't see any other information coming back.